# how can i remove the null values in two columns to show only data

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have requirement where i have converted row values into columns but what i'm trying to remove null rows and show only data

```
declare @t table (id int,keys varchar(10),val varchar(10))
insert into @t (id,keys,val)values (1,'name','hulk'),(2,'age','22'),(3,'name','ironman'),(4,'age','35')
;with CTE AS (
Select  [name],CAST([age] AS INT)age from (
select id,keys,val from @t )t
PIVOT(MAX(val) for KEYS in ([name],[age]))P

GROUP BY [name],age)
Select  (C.name),(C.AGE) from CTE C 
LEFT JOIN CTE cc ON c.age = cc.age AND c.name = cc.name
```

result :

```
name    AGE
NULL    22
NULL    35
hulk    NULL
ironman NULL
```

Desired result set :

```
name    AGE
hulk    22
ironman 35
```

Comment: How do you know who's 22 and who's 35?

Comment: Is your table always 2 attributes, name and age?   Or can we always assume age attribute immediately follows the name attribute?   Can you change the table design?

Comment: SELECT name, age FROM <TABLE> WHERE name IS NOT NULL;

Comment: @Sparky i know this design is wrong but the data came like this so i need to write on fly query to simplify the data

Comment: OK, I added an answer to the list below.   Sounds like you've got some possible solutions

Answer (score 2):

Your data structure is quite flawed, because it doesn't have a person identity.

If you assume that "name" begins each record, there is something you can do:

```
select max(case when keys = 'name' then val end) as name,
       max(case when keys = 'age' then val end) as age
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when keys = 'name' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) as numnames
      from @t t
     ) t
group by numnames;
```

This very much relies on the fact that `id` encodes the ordering of the records (as in your sample data).  I would suggest that you include another identifier, if that is possible.

EDIT:

The equivalent query in pre-2012 versions of SQL Server:

```
select max(case when keys = 'name' then val end) as name,
       max(case when keys = 'age' then val end) as age
from (select t.*, tt.numnames
      from @t t cross apply
           (select count(*) as numnames
            from @t t2
            where t2.id <= t.id and t2.keys = 'name'
           ) tt
     ) t
group by numnames;
```

Comment: how can i handle in this above query scenario i know that we can handle in Summary and Max Case but in pivot how we going to achieve it @gordon

Comment: i have tried your above query it is showing message of incorrect syntax near order

Comment: @mohan111 . . . What version of SQL Server are you using?  Cumulative sums have been supported since SQL Server 2012.  You can do something similar with `cross apply`.

Comment: i'm using sql 2008 r2 version @gordon

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Gordon, the data structure is flawed.   If however, you can always assume the age key ID follows the name key ID by 1, the following will work.  But if you can change the table structure, so much the better..

```
declare @t table (id int,keys varchar(10),val varchar(10))
insert into @t (id,keys,val)
values (1,'name','hulk'),(2,'age','22'),(3,'name','ironman'),(4,'age','35')


select nc.id,nc.val as Name,xx.age
from @t nc
join (select id,val as Age from @t where keys='age') xx on xx.id=nc.id+1
where keys='name'
```

However, the code relies on possibly a bad assumption about the keys...

Comment: thanks @sparky i got the result set but can you suggest me in above pivot query

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the original row-wise table design is flawed by lacking another person indentity.  For example, a SSN, or any unique person identifier key, in addition to just name, and age, and the row id.

Comment: This is a very valid point, but not an answer to the question.     Often, the user cannot change the table structure, although I hope that is not the case in this example....

Answer (score 0):

if I am guessing correct you want a pivot view on name and age and hence the unusual format of data. What you can do is relate the data, like `name:hulk` and `age:22`, and so on. So what you can do is:

```
declare @t table (id int,keys varchar(10),val varchar(10))
insert into @t (id,keys,val)values (1,'name','hulk'),(1,'age','22'),
(2,'name','ironman'),(2,'age','35');
with CTE AS (
Select  [name],CAST([age] AS INT)age from (
select id,keys,val from @t )t
PIVOT(MAX(val) for KEYS in ([name],[age]))P
GROUP BY [name],age)
Select  (C.name),(C.AGE) from CTE C 
LEFT JOIN CTE cc ON c.age = cc.age AND c.name = cc.name
```

Once the relation is created, you will get the desired output. I created the relation by entering Id as 1 for `name:hulk` with `age:22` by saying that the data entered are for the same Id here `Id:1` or could be any object you have defined in your application using this data.

Comment: The value of the `Id` column specifies that the data are for the same `Id`. Meaning that when you enter `name` and `age` separately, into two different rows, you need a relation between the two data. Mainly here you are saying that the two different entries are for the same person `hulk` or `ironman`. This relation needs to be specified with some common key. Hence the `Id`.